# Eliminar componente deseado en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Supongamos que tengo un array con componentes, cada componente tiene su propio index y su nombre. Pongamosle que es un array de tamaño 5 y los componentes se llaman asi: LANZA 1, LANZA 2, LANZA 3, LANZA 4 y LANZA 5.

LANZA 1 está en la posicion 0, LANZA 2 en la posicion 1, y asi sucesivamente.  Yo tengo una función la cual se encarga de eliminar la LANZA seleccionada. El problema que estoy teniendo es que si borro todas las LANZA, y creo una nueva,  el nombre de la LANZA nueva va a obtener la cantidad de elementos que se guardaron en el ultimo array y sumarle uno, es decir, si en el primer array habia 5 elementos (el cual el ultimo componente se llamaba LANZA 5), la nueva LANZA se va a llamar LANZA 6. Este error lo arreglé utilizando el metodo `.splice()`.

Pero esto me borra el elemento siguiente al componente que quiero eliminar, es decir, Si tengo LANZA 1, LANZA 2, LANZA 3, LANZA 4 y LANZA 5, y quiero borrar LANZA 3, con el metodo '`.splice()`' estoy borrando LANZA 4. Este es el metodo que estoy utilizando:

```
 const removeDeviceElement = (index: number) => {
    let d = cloneWithoutReference(deviceForms);
    let df = cloneWithoutReference(formDeviceValues);
    if (d && d[index]) {
      d[index] = { showDevice: false };
      d.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if (df && df[index]) {
      df[index].delete = true;
    }
    setFormDeviceValues(df);
    setDeviceForms(d);
  };
```

Aqui dejo una imagen:

Acá tengo LANZA 1, LANZA 2, LANZA 3 y LANZA 4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo quiero borrar LANZA 2, se me borra LANZA 4, y si quiero borrar LANZA 2 denuevo, elimino LANZA 3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilicé un `console.log(index)` en `removeDeviceElement` y los index estan llegando correctamente.

éste es el componente de cada LANZA:

```
   <CardComponent
      dashboard
      withDelete
      marginTop={"0"}
      className="form-device-column"
      title={ `Lanza ${index + 1}`}
      deleteAction={() => removeDeviceElement(index)}
    >
```

En resumen, necesito que si tengo LANZA 1, LANZA 2, LANZA 3, LANZA 4, y borro LANZA 3, LANZA 4 seria la nueva LANZA 3

CardComponent.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Image, Nav, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Paths } from "../../config/paths";
import { alertColor } from "../../shared/helper";;
import DeleteIcon from "../../assets/icons/svg/SiloBagPage/trash.svg";

const CardComponent = (props: any) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {
    backgroundColor,
    borderAlertColor,
    children,
    dashboard,
    height,
    marginTop,
    minHeight,
    showInMap,
    title,
    titleCount,
    withoutBorder,
    withDelete,
    withAlertBorder,
    hideOverflow,
    bodyClassName,
    activeAlerts,
    className,
    style,
    deleteAction,
    record,
  } = props;


  const cleanAndNavigate = () => {
    navigate(Paths.COUNTRYSIDES_MAPS);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      style={{
        maxHeight: minHeight,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor && backgroundColor,
        borderColor: borderAlertColor,
        ...props.style,
      }}
      className={
        `cardComponent
      ${dashboard ? `p-2 p-md-3` : ``} ${
          marginTop || marginTop === "" ? marginTop : `mt-5`
        }
      ${
        withoutBorder && !withAlertBorder
          ? `cardWithoutAnyBorder`
          : withAlertBorder
          ? `cardWithAlertBorder`
          : `cardWithoutAnyBorder`
      }
      ` + props.className
      }
    >
      {title && (
        <Card.Header
          className={
            "cardCustomHead d-inline-flex justify-content-between align-center"
          }
          style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem", paddingRight: "1rem" }}
        >
          <span className="fw-bold-500 fs-6">
            {title}{" "}
            {titleCount && (
              <span className="cardTitleCount">({titleCount})</span>
            )}
          </span>
          {activeAlerts && (
            <button
              className="active-alerts"
              onClick={() => activeAlerts.onClick()}
            >
              Alertas activas ({activeAlerts.alertsCount})
            </button>
          )}
          {showInMap && (
            <Nav.Link
              className={"cardCustomLink fw-bold-500"}
              onClick={() => cleanAndNavigate()}
            >
              Ver en mapa
            </Nav.Link>
          )}
          {withDelete && record === `Nuevo silobolsa ` ? (
            <Nav.Link
              className={"cardCustomLink fw-bold-500"}
              onClick={() => deleteAction()}
            >
              <Image
                style={{
                  width: 12.25,
                  height: 14,
                }}
                className={"align-middle"}
                src={DeleteIcon}
              />
            </Nav.Link> ) : null}        
        </Card.Header>
      )}
      <Card.Body
        style={{
          height: height ? height : undefined,
          maxHeight: minHeight ? minHeight : undefined,
          overflow: hideOverflow ? "hidden" : undefined,
          overflowY: title ? "auto" : "unset",
        }}
        className={bodyClassName}
      >
        <Row className="justify-content-between">{children}</Row>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

Comment: Aqui agrega index+1 `deleteAction={() => removeDeviceElement(index+1)}`, confirma si funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo está definido `index`? ¿Podrías añadir el código del componente padre que contiene la lista de `CardComponents`?

Comment: @g.4 si lo hago de esa manera se estaría borrando la LANZA siguiente.

Comment: En las props de `cardComponent` aqui `title={ `Lanza ${index + 1}`}` estas pasando indice + 1, pero luego para eliminarlo pasas solo indice `deleteAction={() => removeDeviceElement(index)}`, por eso sería bueno ver de donde viene `index`